# How to wrap slotted elements individually

Tags: javascript, html, shadow-dom, custom-element

Is there a way to wrap each individual element slotted into the shadow dom for a specific slot name?

Assume the Markup looks similar to this

```html
<custom-element>
  <div name="item">item 1</div>
  <div name="item">item 2</div>
</custom-element>
```

Currently, the render is similar to:

```html
<custom-element>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div name="item">item 1</div>
    <div name="item">item 2</div>
  </div>
</custom-element>
```

How would I go about wrapping the slotted elements to output similar to:

```html
<custom-element>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div name="item">item 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div name="item">item 2</div>
  </div>
</custom-element>
```

My current (flawed) approach:

```js
customElements.define('custom-element', class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    let shadow = this.attachShadow({mode: open});
    shadow.innerHTML = `
      <div class="wrap">
        <slot name="item"></slot>
      </div>
    `;
  }
});
```

Comment: no, you'll need to write a few Javascript lines to distribute the elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you change your approach as to the wrapping of the children. The simplest way would be to just add the missing HTML as a child of the slotted div like the example below. You would still be able to style the slotted element with the `::slotted` pseudo selector.

```js
customElements.define('custom-element', class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    let shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadow.innerHTML = `
      <style>
        ::slotted([slot="item"]) {
            border: 1px solid black;
            padding: 15px;
        }
      </style>
      <slot name="item"></slot>
    `;

  }
});
```

```html
<custom-element>
  <div slot="item">
    <div class="wrap">item 1</div>
  </div>
  <div slot="item">
    <div class="wrap">item 2</div>
  </div>
</custom-element>
```

The reason behind this approach is that the wrap ultimately belongs to the *child* element and should come with each child. The result would be similar to what you request.

Although, if you do want to add wrapping to the element dynamically, then you could do with the [`slotchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/slotchange_event) event. The event is fired whenever a slot has been filled and can be listened to from the `ShadowRoot` element. In the event callback loop over the `assignedElements` (which are the elements in the slot) and alter their `innerHTML` value.

```js
customElements.define('custom-element', class MyCustomElement extends HTMLElement {

  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);

    let shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadow.innerHTML = `<slot name="item"></slot>`;

    shadow.addEventListener('slotchange', event => {
      const { target } = event;
      const assignedElements = target.assignedElements();
      for (const element of assignedElements) {
        if (element.querySelector('.wrap') === null) {
          const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
          wrapper.className = 'wrap';
          
          for (const node of element.childNodes) {
            wrapper.appendChild(node);
          }
          
          element.append(wrapper);
        }
      }
    });

  }
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<custom-element>
  <div slot="item">item 1</div>
  <div slot="item">
    <div class="wrap">item 2</div>
  </div>
</custom-element>
```

Comment: The slotchange event was what I was looking for.

Comment: The handler for the event can be executed multiple times, which will wrap persisting elements multiple times. Even if it does not cause observable effects, it is just bad coding.Additionally, editing the assigned elements is not very clean - outside code may still hold references to these items and may want to access or even change it.

Comment: @j_kubik Thank you for the feedback. I added a check which will only add the `wrap` class whenever an element with that class doesn't yet exist in the slotted element. This should prevent any redundant wrapping. I've also changed the way the wrapper is created. Now the nodes are *moved* into a wrapper instead of assigning a string to the `innerHTML` setter. I look forward to your feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem, and this is the solution I came up with: re-targeting the item slots. I have a single "main" slot, which should always be empty - on every slotchange event, I iterate over the new items, create a new wrapper for each of them and create a new  with dynamically generated name inside each wrapper. Then I change the "slot" attribute of the original item to move it to that slot.

```
customElements.define('buttons', class extends HTMLElement {

    __allocateId()
    {
        var i = 0;
        while ( this.__buttons.has( "btn" + i ) ) {
            ++i;
        }
        return "btn" + i;
    }

    __onButtonSlotChange(button)
    {
        if (button.contentSlot.assignedNodes({flatten: true}).length == 0) {
            this.__buttons.delete(button.id);
            button.remove();
        }
    }

    __onMainSlotChange() {
        for (var element of this.mainSlot.assignedElements({flatten: true})) {
            var button = document.createElement('arrow-button');
            button.id = this.__allocateId();
            this.shadowRoot.appendChild(button);

            var subSlot = document.createElement('slot');
            subSlot.name = button.id;
            button.appendChild(subSlot);
            button.contentSlot = subSlot;
            subSlot.addEventListener('slotchange', this.__onButtonSlotChange.bind(this, button));

            element.setAttribute("slot", button.id);

            this.__buttons.set(button.id, button);
        }
    }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.__buttons = new Map();
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({mode: 'open'});

        this.mainSlot = document.createElement('slot');
        shadowRoot.appendChild(this.mainSlot);

        var buttonList = document.createElement('div');
        shadowRoot.appendChild(buttonList);

        this.mainSlot.addEventListener('slotchange', this.__onMainSlotChange.bind(this));
    }
});
```

This has minimal impact on the original objects and the entire component behaves correctly upon any modifications to the "buttoned" code - eg. item removal triggers removal of the corresponding button.